# Rmarkdown table of contents disappears after 1 second in HTML knit document

Tags: html, r-markdown

I'm knitting from Rmarkdown and this is my header:

```
---
title: 'My Title'
output:
  html_document:
    theme: journal
    code_folding: show
    toc: true
    number_sections: yes
---

> Pipeline for dataset can be found at this markdown file

# Gene {.tabset .tabset-pills}

## Parsing VCF file
```

The document continues to include another "##" header and a few "###" headers. 
When I knit the document, my TOC is not there, but when I refresh the page I can see it flash up, but then it disappears...?

Comment: I just see h1 headers, but no h2 headers, just when refreshing it, they appear for a very short time. Is this the problem you are describing?

Comment: Yes this is the problem

Comment: As you are using tabset, only the header 1 will be shown in the toc. The headers that are used in the tabset pane (here the header 2) won't be show in the TOC as they will be removed by a JS script. I think you see them briefly before they disappear because your browser has a delay for the JS execution. I can't reproduce on my end I don't see it flashing. 

Is this TOC disappearance you mention happening only when using `.tabset` ?